# Seating System, problems at loops in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I am making a seating app in Python which takes a list of 10 names and gives every student a seat. The seats are 2 row of 5 seats.

I wrote a simple script to do that, but I am stuck at looping the seats for the students. Here is my code:

```
from pprint import pprint as pp 

C = "ABCDE"
R = range(0, 2)

students= ["rob", "tim", "kaleb", "josh", "victoria", "amy", "fred", "xander", "cody", "dump man"]

seats = [{str(y)+ltr:"EMPTY" for ltr in C} for y in R]

for names in range(10):
   for i in range(2):
      for letters in C:
         for s in range(1):
                print(f'{i}{letters}')
                seats[i][f"{i}{letters}"]=students[names]


pp(seats)
```

As you can see, at the loop I am iterating over the letters and numbers of SEATS. However, when coming to iterate of students names, it always gives me 10. Can you please help!

Comment: Where is `pp`?..

Comment: pp is prity print

Comment: Please show expected result

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [mcve] and update your post accordingly. Mainly, take time to formalize your problem and state the expected output.

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
C = "ABCDE"
number_of_rows = 2
R = range(number_of_rows)
seats_per_row = 5

students= ["rob", "tim", "kaleb", "josh", "victoria", "amy", "fred", "xander", "cody", "dump man"]

seats = [{str(y)+ltr:"EMPTY" for ltr in C} for y in R]

for row in range(number_of_rows):
    for seat in range(seats_per_row):
        letter = C[seat]
        name = students[row * seats_per_row + seat]
        seats[row][f"{row}{letter}"]=name

print(seats)
```

**OUTPUT:**

`[{'0A': 'rob', '0B': 'tim', '0C': 'kaleb', '0D': 'josh', '0E': 'victoria'}, {'1A': 'amy', '1B': 'fred', '1C': 'xander', '1D': 'cody', '1E': 'dump man'}]`

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_

Comment: it's definitely a good solution! better if had been explained.